# JsonSerializationException: Cannot create and populate list type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am dealing with the error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot create and populate list type UpdatePurchaseOrders.SalesOrderSummaryCollection. Path '', line 1,
> position 1.

The JSON:

```
[
    {
        "OrderNumber": "017323906",
        "PONumber": "PON023329",
        "DocType": "ZOR",
        "Status": "On Hold",
        "Total": 83899.1600,
        "DateEntered": "3/2/2021 11:05 AM",
        "LastChanged": "3/4/2021 7:19 AM"
    }
]
```

I have two classes I am testing. The first one is an object with properties matching the JSON.

```
[JsonArray]
public class SalesOrderSummary
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string PONumber { get; set; }
    public string DocType { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public float Total { get; set; }
    public string DateEntered { get; set; }
    public string LastChanged { get; set; }
}
```

The second I'm calling a *collection* object that just has an array of the first object.

```
[JsonArray]
public class SalesOrderSummaryCollection 
{
    public SalesOrderSummary[] result { get; set; }
}
```

I have used this exact concept in another project last year and it worked perfectly fine - without using any JSON attributes.
In this current project I can attempt to deserialize to either class and I get the same error. If I use **`SalesOrderSummaryCollection`** and remove the `[JsonArray]` attribute, then I get the error ending in:

> [...] because the type requires a JSON object

which I hesitantly say I understand but I did not receive this error in the *last year project* I mentioned.
So I don't know why the same concept between two projects is behaving differently or how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have no idea why you have the `[JsonArray]` attribute on the `SalesOrderSummary` class. Your JSON isn't an object, it's a collection. Deserialize it into either a `SalesOrderSummary[]` or a `List<SalesOrderSummary>`. The `SalesOrderSummaryCollection` is likely getting in the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON contains an array of Objects, so it could be parsed with:

```
var parsedArray = JArray.Parse(json);
```

You're trying t deserialize to an object of type `SalesOrderSummaryCollection`, which defines and array of `SalesOrderSummary` objects.
The JSON doesn't contain any root objects, thus the exception.
To deserialize to that object type, your JSON should start with:

```
{ "result": [ { // Object 1 }, { // Object N } ] }
```

It cannot be decorated with `[JsonArray]`, because, well, it's not an array.

The direct solution is to deserialize to a collection of `SalesOrderSummary` objects, either `List<SalesOrderSummary>` or `SalesOrderSummary[]`:

```
var salesOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SalesOrderSummary[]>(json);
// or 
var salesOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SalesOrderSummary>>(json);
```